# posting with web client returning a 400 bad request

Tags: c#, webclient

EDIT.  The people who suggested fiddler were great. Turns out the API i was posting to freaked out because the c# application had no user-agent. So adding one to the header fixed it

I'm trying to use c# web client to to post to an api but seem to be running into a wall.  I'm trying to use this code to post json to an api however all i get is 400 bad request and i'm not sure what is going on.

```
output = "{ \"id\": \"xxxxxx\", \"company\": \"test\", \"fname\": \"test\", \"lname\": \"test\", \"member_level\": \"Member\",\"status\": \"active\"}";

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.Headers.Add("token", "validtoken");
     client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
     client.UploadString(new Uri("url"), "POST", output);
}
```

I was able to use powershell to successfully post using a webrequest so i know the url and auth token are valid. but for whatever reason i can't get c# to post correctly. This is the working powershell command

```
curl url -Method POST -H @{"token" = "token"} -ContentType "application/json" -Body '{ "id": "xxxxxx", "company": "test", "fname": "test", "lname": "test", "member_level": "test","status": "active"}'
```

Comment: Install [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and view the two HTTP requests. What are the differences.

Comment: works with Fiddler for me - make sure "url" is a genuine value, e.g. `code`http://127.0.0.1:8888`code`

Comment: Any reason for not using HttpClient?

Comment: You might also want to catch any `WebException` and inspect the `Response` inside the exception. Maybe the API sends additional info what went wrong.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider alas no more additional information.

Comment: @Liam I installed fiddler and the only difference is c# is sending Connection: Keep-alive as a header. Any idea how i can remove that?

Comment: That shouldn't prompt a 400. There is no other differences? At all? Can you post the two raw HTTP requests? Can you see the 400 response code in fiddler?

Comment: public string UploadString(string address,  string data ), try using this instead of new Uri()

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
client.UploadString(new Uri("url"), "POST", output);
```

use

```
client.UploadData(url, "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use built-in features of C# to keep code clean. When possible create classes that describe contracts for API communication. Use HttpClient when there is no need for low-level control. HttpClient can send these objects as JSON and you usually do not need to care about serialization issues.

This code should make a POST after you replaced url parts. Since you do not send the TOKEN this should raise a 401 error - you are not authorized. Add your valid token, delete the comment and this request should work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string MemberLevel { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void CreateUser(User user)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // posts to https://yourawesomewebsite.com/api/users
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://yourawesomewebsite.com");             
            //client.Headers.Add("token", "validtoken");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJson("api/users", user);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {     
        // Create a new user
        User user = new User
        { 
            Id = "xxxxx",
            Company = "Test",
            FName = "Test",
            LName = "Test",
            MemberLevel = "Test",
            Status = "Active"
        };

        CreateUser(user);
    }
}
```

Reference

- [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)
- [HttpClient, the best of both worlds](http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/)